# What does the symbol on the tank trooper helmet mean?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, symbols, empire

There is what looks like a headphones symbol (or even a rotated telephone symbol) on the tank trooper helmets from *Rogue One*. What are these symbols for / what do they mean?

[image: diagram]

Comment: Are you sure it's a symbol, and not some microphone-type cover for external audio pickup?  The shape could be to help determine the directional source of the sound.  to me it looks inset, rather than painted, suggesting there's a hole there.

Comment: It's definitely a hole if [this toy](https://artoyz.com/shop/en/toyz/8478-funko-pop-combat-assault-tank-trooper-sdcc-2017-exclusive-sw-rogue-one-889698147200.html) is accurate.

Answer (score 5):

You can see in the original concept art (courtesy of [*The Art of Rogue One*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story)) that these are intended to be cut holes, presumably to allow better hearing while operating a tank.

[image]

This [Anovos](https://www.secretcompassonline.com/ANOVOS-Tank-Trooper-Helmet/) prop replica helmet (moulded from the original prop helmets seen in the film) also shows the cuts in more detail. They clearly go all the way through the helmet and presumably lead into the ['auditory sensors'](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Stormtrooper_armor/Legends?file=RiddellTKBP.jpg) that are standard on all varieties of trooper helmets

[image]